# How to read multiline Azure Key Vault secret in Azure Devops Release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, multiline, azure-keyvault, private-key

I'm having trouble using a multiline Azure Key Vault value inside an Azure Release Pipeline...

I put a multiline value (RSA private key) into Azure Key Vault [using the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/multiline-secrets):

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name "vault" --name "secret" --file "pk.pem"
```

This works and I can see the multiline secret in the portal.

Locally using CLI I can also do:

```
pk=$(az keyvault secret show \
--name "ssh-private-key" \
--vault-name $vault \
--query "value")
```

This returns a somewhat crappy value (yes including the double quotes):

> "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIG4wIBAA .... JtpyW\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

I can manage to work with this and send the value to a file like so:

```
pk="${pk%\"}" #remove first quote
pk="${pk#\"}" #remove last quote


echo $pk | sed 's|\\n|\n|g' | # replace with actual newlines
while IFS= read -r line; do   # loop through lines
  echo "$line" >> pk.pem      # write to file per line
done
```

This works and I can login to my server using `ssh -i pk.pem user@server`

---

But when running the same script in the Azure Devops Release pipeline (also using Bash on a Linux agent) the exact same script fails... I'm also having trouble inspecting the actual value as the log masks all values related to the secret...

[image: Azure Devops Release Pipeline]

Any guide on how to debug or work with actually *reading* multiline values instead of just storing them would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a troubleshooting advice:

The error "`Host key verification failed.`" doesn't just occur when the key is incorrect. Most of the time, it doesn't refer to your key.

So I recommend you firstly try the connection with a simple value to see if it works on Azure DevOps.

What's more, maybe an [SSH service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-ssh) can help you with what you're doing. Go to Project Settings -> Service connections -> Create service connection -> SSH to create one.

Comment: The server is dynamically generated and assigned a new IP, so creating a service connection is not an option. However you were right on the "Host key verification failed" - after about 100 release tries I looked over it and indeed I needed to clear the entry in the `.ssh/known_hosts`. Moreover for anyone coming here there is a method `az keyvault secret download` which isn't documented in the page about "multi-line" secret in Azure. Using that solved my issue around new lines and quotes!